# Convert 3D vector points to LAS data for use in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point-cloud

I have a vector layer of points with 3D coordinates and one numerical category attribute. I would like to convert these to a LAS-file which can be visualised in QGIS with the attribute as a component value.

I have tried using FME with the PointCloudCombiner and LAS-writer. QGIS loads the LAS-file but does not recognize any components for use in symbology (not even XYZ), although the extent shows up in the right spot.

So, how do I turn 3D vector points into a LAS file which QGIS will recognize?
I have access to FME Oracle Edition, QGIS and PDAL. And could get other FOSSGIS tools as well as needed.

Comment: I'm right now trying to open a LAS file in QGIS. The software doesn't recognize RBG and intensity values. After two hours is still loading the file with classification symbology (it's around 68% so far) while ArcGIS Pro and Global Mapper the file is opened without issues in a few seconds. Maybe the problem isn't the process of file creation but QGIS

Comment: @aldo_tapia I have opened multi million point LAS files in QGIS with no problem with very fast performance (version 3.24) and have no issues styling them with both RGB and other components. My only problem is the LAS files that I have created from vector point files with FME.